# How to display the difference between 2 columns in a table

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am having an Audit Table that displays 2 columns OLD Data, New data which are in XML while displaying the table, I want only the differences between the 2 columns to be listed.

I have converted the data to XML to present my old and new data and I have removed the XML initialization for easy readability.

**Controller**

```
 public async Task < IActionResult > History(string RefNum) {

     if (RefNum == null) {
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
     var obj = await (from x in _db.AuditModel select x).Where(x => x.RefNum.Equals(RefNum)).ToListAsync();

     if (obj == null) {
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }

     return PartialView(obj);
 }
```

**View Page**

```
@model IEnumerable<Flight_info.Models.AuditModel>
<div>
   <div class="modal-header">
      <h2 class="modal-title">
         HISTORY
      </h2>
      <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" align="right">&times;</button>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
      <table class="table" style="table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>
                  @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RefNum)
               </th>
               <th>
                  @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ChangeMade)
               </th>
               <th>
                  @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OldData)
               </th>
               <th>
                  @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NewData)
               </th>
               <th>
                  @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModifiedOn)
               </th>
               <th>
                  @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModifiedBY)
               </th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
            <tr>
               <td>
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RefNum)
               </td>
               <td>
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ChangeMade)
               </td>
               <td>
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OldData)
               </td>
               <td>
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NewData)
               </td>
               <td>
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ModifiedOn)
               </td>
               <td>
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ModifiedBY)
               </td>
            </tr>
            }
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <div>
         <a asp-action="Index">Back to List </a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
[This is currently my output][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeNHk.png
```

> But I want only the differences to be displayed. Please Help.

Comment: I found a solution using XML DIFF, but i have trouble implementing them. Pls help in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution myself.Instead of using XML i converted my objects to json and i used JSON DIFF.
While displaying i used jquery to dynamically create a table to display the key and value pairs

Answer (score 0):

1- If you want to list only the rows that OldData != NewData, then use filter in Where clause. such as below:

```
 var obj = await (from x in _db.AuditModel select x)
.Where(x => x.RefNum.Equals(RefNum) && x.OldData != x.NewData).ToListAsync();
```

2-If you want to show all rows and display difference value of OldData and NewData then write below code in your view

```
<td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OldData - item.NewData)
</td>
```

Comment: My old Data and new Data are in xml format. I want to show the diff in those xml data.